# Android File Transferで端末が認識されない

Tags: android, macos

Android端末を自分のMacにUSBで接続してAndroid File Transferを起動すると、「Android搭載端末が見つかりません」と表示され、何も画面に出てきません。Android StudioなどではAndroid端末は認識されており、メディアデバイス（MTP）にもチェックが入っています。USBデバッグにもチェックが入っています。ということは、この端末がAndroid File Transferを利用できない端末ということなのでしょうか？現在使用している端末は「MOTOROLA 201M」です。他にAndroid File Transferを利用できるようにする方法はないのでしょうか？すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、Android 端末本体の[設定]->[開発者向けオプション]->[USBデバック]にチェックが入っていますでしょうか？

Comment: はい、USBデバッグにチェックは入れてあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それではステータスバーのUSB設定アイコンからプルダウンメニューを表示させて「USB connection」か「USB接続」をクリックしてみて下さい。その時に表示される内容について教えていただけますか？

Comment: メディアデバイス（MTP）とカメラ（PTP）の二つのチェック項目が表示され、現在はMTPの方にチェックが入っている状態です。

Comment: それであれば問題はないですね。。。お力になれずすみません。

Comment: いえいえ、こちらこそお時間を割いていただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

以前MacでGalaxy S3が認識されなかった時にはPTPを選択したら上手くいきましたが、PTPにしても認識されませんか？

http://jmsnews.blog38.fc2.com/blog-entry-30.html

Comment: すみません、PTPで試してみましたが依然「Android搭載端末が見つかりません」のメッセージのままでした。

Answer (score 1):

データ転送のUSBですか？
充電機能のみを備えたUSBも存在しますので、ご確認を。

Answer (score 1):

Android 6.0にアップデートして、しばらくFile Transferを使っていなかったので、充電時にmacと接続したときに"Can't access device strage"表示が出ても、無視していました。

今日、音楽ファイルを転送しようとしたときに、質問者の方のように困ってしまい、ここにたどり着きました。上記のおこたえのように対応しようとしましたが、6.0では、「設定」に「開発者オプション」がなく、困りました。

そこで、端末のロックを解除状態にして（時間を10分にして）、純正USBコードを抜き差ししてから、上から下にひとゆびしゅっとスワイプすると、「USBを充電に使用　タップするとその他のオプションが表示」というタブが出ました。タップすると、「USBの使用」のタイトルで、「充電のみ/MTP/PTP/MIDI」がボタンで選べるようになります。ここでMTPを選ぶと、File Transferが認識されて、音楽ファイルを転送できました。

コードを抜き差しするとか、ロックの時間を長くするとか、テレビを叩くみたいなむかし風のやりかたなのですが、目的は達したので、ここに書いておきます。どなたかのお役に立ちますように。

Comment: 同様の症状で悩んでいましたが、user12750さんのを参考に解決しました。
設定画面でのMTPの選択だけでなく、ケーブルを挿した際のに通知される
「USBを充電に使用」からMTPの選択で接続することが出来ました、 おそらくケーブル接続の際に毎回明示的にMTPを使うことを選択する必要がある
仕様に変わったのだと思います。